# How Do I Interpolate a Pandas Dataframe With Another Dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, time, interpolation

I have two dataframes "df" and "fd". The time column of "df" is in 2mins frequency, while the "Time" columns of "fd" is in 1min frequency. How do I interpolate "fd" to have the same time interval with "df" (2mins) while they retain their individual elements for other columns. Both Dataframe should have same time intervals. See attached images,

[image: df]

[image: fd]

The dataframes are in datetime formats.
However, this does not give the expected results.

```
# Interpolate the power values in fd DataFrame using time values from df DataFrame
interpolated_fd = df_reset.set_index('Time').resample('2T').first().merge(fd[['Time', 'power(dB)']], on='Time', how='left').interpolate(method='linear')

# Print the interpolated DataFrame
print(interpolated_fd)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be resolved using `pd.merge_asof` command as it works like joins so if you apply this by providing both data frames it will resolve the issue.

Moreover, I'm attaching the helping tutorial link for further assistance.

[tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pandas-merge_asof-function-in-python/)